# add row to a data frame that calculates sums of all numeric columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have a data frame with first two columns characters and the rest doubles.
I want to add a row at the bottom that has the word 'Total' in the first two columns and calculates the sum of the column values in the rest.

For example let's use:

```
segment<- c('seg1', 'seg1', 'seg2', 'seg2', 'seg3', 'seg3')
subSegment<- c('subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2')
var.1<- c(100, 20, 30, 50, 40, 40)
var.2<- c(200, 30, 30, 70, 30, 140)
var.3<- c(50, 50, 40, 20, 30, 40)
var.4<- c(60, 50, 35, 53, 42, 20)
df<- data.frame(segment, subSegment, var.1, var.2, var.3, var.4)
```

This is how I did it:

```
df%>% # now need to add a row with totals
    add_row( segment="Total",subSegment="Total", var.1 = sum(.$var.1), var.2= sum(.$var.2), var.3 = sum(.$var.3), var.4 = sum(.$var.4))
```

Obviously the names and values are just examples but in my real problem I have over 8 variables and doing things this way is a waste of time.
I am looking for a more general solution that just says to add_row with first 2 columns "Total" and then `....=sum(.$....)` for all columns after the third.

Maybe using something like `sapply(df[c(3:ncol(df))]`.

Comment: It seems you have used the answer to this question in a following question. However you have not accepted the answer: When your question is answered it is customary [to click on the accept answer option and upvote if you have sufficient reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [What does it mean to accept an answer
](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The janitor package has this ready to go:

```r
library(janitor)

df %>%
  adorn_totals("row", fill = "Total")

 segment subSegment var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
    seg1    subseg1   100   200    50    60
    seg1    subseg2    20    30    50    50
    seg2    subseg1    30    30    40    35
    seg2    subseg2    50    70    20    53
    seg3    subseg1    40    30    30    42
    seg3    subseg2    40   140    40    20
   Total      Total   280   500   230   260
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's add an additional row, with `Total`, `Total` in two columns, and let's calculate the sums along columns with `colSums` starting from column 3 till end `ncol(df)`.

```
df<- rbind(df, c("Total", "Total", colSums(df[,3:ncol(df)], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: This would be a more valuable answer if it included some explanation beyond the code itself.